# Why do the majority of my Google Analytics referrals show up as “ad.doubleclick.net”?

Tags: google-analytics

We do not advertise on Google's network.

The URLs of the referring pages in GA resemble those used to serve ads on my own page. What could be going on here?

Comment: [DoubleClick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DoubleClick) is part of Google's ad network. It would be helpful to know more about your other traffic in order to comment on why that would represent the _majority_, but it's likely just traffic via the ads. [Auto-tagging](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/1752125?hl=en) will attach a parameter to the URL people click through to help you tell which ad was clicked for each visit to your site.

Comment: @dan, thanks for the advice. We don't run ads using Google's ad network; the referring URLs are those of ads embedded on our page. By majority, I mean 52% - Twitter is next on about 9%.

Comment: I see you updated your question. It's still a little confusing though: `The URLs of the referring pages in GA resemble those used to serve ads on my own page.` So you do have an ad network, but not through Google or any affiliates that might use the DoubleClick network?

Comment: @dan, thanks for your patience. We serve ads on the page, and the ad networks use doubleclick. We don't advertise our own service at all.

Comment: This is likely _self-referrals_. Take a look at the section here on [Ignoring self-referrals](http://moz.com/blog/cross-domain-subdomain-tracking-in-google-analytics).

Comment: I've updated the settings as described in that blog post, adding the www. cname which wasn't there before. This didn't make a difference.

Comment: Maybe you can add a screenshot of your Google Analytics and copy the corresponding entries in your server logs so that others can help you better here.